# Question on Convergence of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The sequence $y_n = \frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3} \dots +\frac{1}{2n}$.   Is $y_n$ convergent or divergent?

What I did:

From Mathematical Induction I derived that $y_n$ is an increasing sequence.
Now, let $y_n$ is bounded above.
Let a set Y = {$y_n$: n ∈ N}. If Y is bounded above, it has to have a supremum. Hence let $M=supY$
Therefore, $y_n \le M$ for every n ∈ N.
Hence, given $\epsilon \gt 0$, there exists some $y_k \in\Bbb Y$ such that $y_k \gt M-\epsilon$
$y_k+\epsilon \gt M$
$M \lt \frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3} \dots +\frac{1}{2k}+\epsilon$
Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2(k+1)}$  Then,
$M \lt \frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3} \dots +\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1}{k+2}+\frac{1}{k+3} \dots +\frac{1}{2k}+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$=$\frac{1}{(k+1)+1}+\frac{1}{(k+1)+2} \dots +\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ =$y_{k+1}$
Hence $M \lt y_{k+1}$ for some $y_{k+1}  \in\Bbb Y$. This is a contradiction which means, Y has no supremum which means Y is not bounded above. Hence Divergent.
I don't understand where did I go wrong in this proof because clearly Y is bounded above because $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+2}+\frac{1}{n+3} \dots +\frac{1}{2n}$ $\lt$ $\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1}+\frac{1}{n+1} \dots +\frac{1}{n+1}$$=$$\frac{n}{n+1}$ $\lt$$1$.
Hence 1 is clearly an upper bound.So, what is wrong with that proof?

Actually I'm not good with proving and I'm trying to improve my reasoning. Help is appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $u_n=\frac{1}{n+1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2n}$, we have
$$u_n=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}{\frac{1}{k}}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{n+k}}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}}\underset{n\rightarrow+\infty}{\longrightarrow}\int_0^1\frac{dx}{1+x}=\ln 2$$
What is wrong in your proof is that you wrote $\frac{1}{k+1}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2(k+1)}<\frac{1}{k+2}+\ldots\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$y_{n+1}-y_n=\frac{1}{n+2}+...+\frac{1}{2n+2}-$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1} -...-\frac{1}{2n}=$$

$$\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac {1}{n+1}=$$

$$\frac{ 1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)}>0$$

On the other hand

$$n\frac{1}{2n}\le y_n \le n\frac{1}{n+1}\le 1$$

thus $(y_n)$ is increasing and bounded and then convergent.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is that you have created a chicken-and-egg situation. First you pick (arbitrary) $\epsilon$. Then, you get $k$ that depends on that $\epsilon$. Then, finally, you pick "$\epsilon$" that depends on $k$. So, either this new "$\epsilon$" is a different $\epsilon$ (in which case you have abused notation by using the same symbol), or it is the same $\epsilon$, which doesn't work (you have already picked it to start with!).

Comment: This is not wrong, for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$, $M-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}<M$, thus there exists $y_k\in Y$ such that $y_k>M-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien is your $k$ in $\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ the same $k$ as the one in $y_k$? Because, yes, there exists $y_{\text{something}}$ bigger than $M-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ - but is this "something" really $k$? I believe OP's argument fundamentally uses the fact that it is the same $k$.

Comment: He should have introcued $y_k$ after defining $\varepsilon$ as $\frac{1}{2k+1}$.

Comment: But ... @Tuvasbien ... the meaning of $y_k$ (actually $y_n$) is defined at the very top, that is why the OP just substitutes it with $\frac{1}{k+1}+\frac{1}{k+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2k}$ in the next step.

Comment: What I meant is that he should have said let $\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$ and $y_{\sigma(k)}\in Y$ such that $y_{\sigma(k)}>M-\frac{1}{2(k+1)}$.

Comment: @Tuvasbien Correct, and then the next step will have something like $\frac{1}{\sigma(k)+1}+\frac{1}{\sigma(k)+2}+\ldots+\frac{1}{2\sigma(k)}$, which is not useful anymore to the point they are trying to make.

Answer (score -1):

Hint: 
$$y_n=\dfrac1n\sum_{k=1}^n\dfrac1{1+\frac{k}{n}}$$ and use Riemann sums.

You can also note that $y_n$ is increasing and bounded since $$\dfrac12=\frac{n}{2n}\le y_n\le\frac{n}{n+1}< 1$$